Stück vs. Teil taking the genitive
I noticed that certain words take the genitive while others seem to just precede the noun. Is there a rule over when such words take the genitive case or is it an irregularity depending on each word? Examples sentences I've found:
ein Stück Land
ein Teil der Vereinigten Staaten

@Alazon has already mentioned part of the solution, but without naming it explicitly:
The Genitiv indicates a relation between two nouns and especially the relation of X is part of Y:

das Dach des Hauses (the roof is part of the house)
das Wasser des Meeres (the part of [all] water which makes up the sea)

This is called genitivus partitivus. This also explains your example:

ein Teil der Vereinigten Staaten

This system is (commonly) not used, though, when dealing with units and quasi-units. It is possible to say

ein Liter Wassers

but this is very uncommon today (see below). Much more common is to say:

ein Liter Wasser

The same goes for quasi-units like "Stück", "Teil", and even other words when they are used in a unit-like capacity, like here "Teller":

zwei Teller Brei (not "Breis")

This is rather describing the amount - the amount of mush which would fill two plates - than the way the mush is served. It could actually be filled into a can.
Notice that using the Genitiv was common in times past. You may find a construction like "ein Teller Breis" or "ein Stück Landes" in older texts, but unlikely so in recent ones.

I can only offer a speculation: Maybe the genitive construction refers to a relation between two things, especially if both nouns come with articles. If "ein Teil der Torte" is on your plate, this implies that there is more where that one came from. If you say "ein Stück Torte" you are not relating to the entire cake, but the word "Torte" rather behaves like a kind of substance. "Stück" then behaves like a measurement. Same with "ein Glas Bier". In contrast, when you say "nur ein Glas von dem Bier haben wir verkauft" (we only sold one glass of that beer), it implies another quantity of beer somewhere else that is left.
